# Вращающийся барабан на ActionScript

Tags: разработка-игр, flash, actionscript, actionscript-3

Flash-игра на ActionScript 3.0.
Есть вращающийся барабан, который по клику останавливается и нужно узнать, какой сектор выпал.
Не хочется изобретать кривой велосипед. Как это обычно делается?

Объект барабана - нарисованный, секторы все разные по размеру и расположены не по порядку. Есть идея прикрутить контрольные точки к месту пересечения секторов, но есть проблема. Для каждой точки нужно указать, значение сектора, за который она, грубо говоря, отвечает. Эти точки можно, наверное, добавлять из библиотеки после того, как нарисован барабан - в нужные места. А есть ли какая-нибудь возможность для добавленного из библиотеки объекта указать свойство?

В голову приходит только дать имя экземпляру с нужным параметром в конце (например, item_1, item_5). Это очень грубый подход? Плюс, у двух точек может  быть одинаковое значение, потому что сектора повторяются.

Как я это вижу:

1. Рисуется барабан
2. В нужные места натыкиваются контрольные точки (объекты одного класса, берутся из библиотеки). Каждой точке дается имя, в котором указан параметр.
3. При добавлении самого барабана на сцену, каким-то образом собираются все контрольные точки в массив. Теперь у них доступны координаты, по которым теперь можно будет вычислить положение барабана и определить выпавший сектор.
4. Получить значение этого сектора (из имени объекта). Как к нему вообще получить доступ из кода?

Я уже сама запуталась)
Основная проблема в том, как получить значение сектора, если барабан нарисованный и все сектора разные?

П.С. Положение барабана можно и по rotation вычислять, наверно, но он ведь может долго крутиться и значение там дикое получается.

П.П.С. Нашла метод hitTestPoint (). Если он действительно высчитывает пересечение по форме, а не по рамке, то узнавать какой сектор выпал еще проще. Но вопрос о том, как передать значение нарисованного сектора, остается в силе.
Если поместить его в текстовое поле внутри сектора, его можно будет считать?

Прошу каких-нибудь подсказок)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рисуется барабан, преобразовывается в MovieClip с точкой трансформации (registration) в центре барабана. Вращение барабана происходит через свойство rotation.

Итоговый угол поворота будет в диапазоне от -180 до 180, поэтому больших значений не будет. Вращение барабана:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(){
    Circle.rotation += 1;
})
```

---

Метод hitTestPoint высчитывает столкновения насколько я помню по рамке. Для того, что бы высчитать по форме круга, можно воспользоваться формулой нахождения расстояние между точками и сравнить с радиусом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого, столкновение по круглому контуру:

```
Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow((Mouse.X - Circle.X), 2) + Math.pow((Mouse.Y - Circle.Y), 2)
) < Circle.Radius
```

То есть расстояние от центра круга до места клика должно быть меньше радиуса.

---

**UPD 1.**

Лучше всего хранить диапазон градусов для каждого сектора, измерив его изначально. К примеру `var sectors = [-180,-80,20,60,180]`. Потом остается только понять, в каком диапазоне лежит угол.

```
for(var i=0; i<sectors.length - 1; i++){
    if(angle >= sectors[i] && angle < sectors[i+1]) trace("сектор "+i+" на барабане");
}
```

**UPD 2.** Можно еще попробовать взять из заготовки углы, оптимизировав немного код выше.

Рисуем наш барабан для приложения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я выбрал линии для того, что бы ими манипулировать как направлением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и далее остается их наложить на барабан (потом, можно их конечно скрыть под ним, отправив на слой ниже или выполнив Arrange->Send To Back). Выставив нужные углы при этом с помощью инструмента вращения и назвав как-нибудь `rotate1, rotate2, rotate3 [...]`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а дальше получить углы дело техники

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    arr.push(this["rotate" + i].rotation);
}
```

Comment: Вот итоговое положение найдено, как теперь мне узнать, какой именно сектор выбран?) Как к секторам их значение прикрутить? Или только сразу высчитать и записать в массив?

Клик кстати будет не по самому барабану, а где-то снаружи.

Comment: Просто хотела избежать ручного высчитывания углов)

Comment: Отлично! Тогда все остальное в общем понятно) Просто никак не могла решиться на это решение :) Спасибо большое)

Comment: @FurryCat, можно значения к барабану так же прикрутить через контрольные точки, но тогда углы будете высчитывать программно через синус-косинус по точке на дуге. Или вроде там можно вращать точку и получить тоже ее rotation потом. Еще можете на будущее посмотреть книгу Джоба Макара "Секреты разработки игр в Macromedia Flash MX", там много полезного кода для разных игр(вращения, столкновения, физика), правда придется с AS 2.0 переносить под AS 3.0.

Comment: @ AlexKrass Я так и не поняла, если добавлять объект из библиотеки прямо в кадр, а не из кода, для него нельзя определить какие-нибудь свойства?

Comment: @FurryCat, можно конечно. Наверное можно будет даже не формировать массив `sectors` заранее как я написал в UPD, а правда использовать использовать точки из библиотеки. Но на память не скажу, давайте я через часиков 8 дополню ответ, как доберусь до компьютера с Adobe Flash. Но все равно, все что выше UPD остается в силе.

Comment: @ AlexKrass Это будет просто замечательно! Сама сейчас без доступа к Flash, поэтому теоретизирую тут, без возможности экспериментировать)

Comment: @FurryCat, я дополнил ответ, как можно получить углы, заранее установив графические ориентиры под вращающийся барабан в редакторе. Правда я еще заметил, что rotation на самом деле принимает значения от - 180 до 180. Поэтому получение остатка не нужно. В общем набросал общую идею, но не тестировал глубоко.

Comment: а как прикрутить свойства к объектам, создаваемым из библиотеки?)

Comment: @FurryCat, посмотрите на рисунок барабана под UPD2. При создании экземпляра в библиотеке или открытии его свойств, надо поставить галочку `Export for ActionScript`, после нажать на карандаш напротив `Class: Drum`. Flash автоматически сгенерирует класс с правильной структурой, в который можно добавлять свои методы и свойства для этого объекта. Правда из редактора они по моему не видны, поэтому придется кодом их устанавливать. Так же, если понадобится, из кода потом можно создавать объекты через `new` (пример: `new Drum()`) и добавлять в кадры через `AddChild`.

Comment: я просто думала, что можно прямо конкретному экземпляру со сцены задать свойство индивидуально) а так все понятно, спасибо большое)

Comment: @FurryCat, вот честно не помню, проверьте: `this["свойство"] = "значение"`. Позволит он так задать или нет. Но опять же только через код AS.